# Dark angels legion praetor in cataphractii size

Tags: warhammer-40k

I know that some heresy models are smaller than the 40k models, so I was wondering for a friend building a dark angels company.

How big is the dark angels legion praetor in cataphractii armour? Is he around the right size around 40k models or would he be laughably too small?

Answer (score 1):

They are about the same as normal terminators, a bit buffier because cataphractii is supposed to be. With the release of intercessors, imo termies are a bit to small in comparison. (Just my taste, I know its fluff) But you can easily fix this visually by putting them on an elevation on its base.